# Concatenar dos array en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, concat

> *Hola para todos. Quiero actualizar los meta datos del post mi tabla de metadato es de clave ,valor y para poder actualizala tengo que usar (bulkCreate) de mi modelo de metadatos, en los dato que resivo del frontend no viene el (id) de cada metadato por lo que tengo que hacer una consulta para obtener dichos id  para poder hacer una array con los datos que recibo del fontend. no se si me doy a entender

esta es la consulta y mapeo de donde obtengo los (id)

```
const metaPost = await MetaPost.findAll({ where: { postId: post.id } });

    const mp = metaPost.map((m) => {
      return { id: m.id };
    });
```

tengo este array
console.log(mp)

```
[
  { id: 1353 }, { id: 1354 },
]
```

esta es el mapeo de donde obtengo los dato que quiero insertar en la base de dato

```
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {
      return {
        meta_key: key,
        meta_value: obj[key],
        postId: post.id,
      };
```

console.log(arr)

```
[
  { meta_key: 'file', meta_value: 'undefined', postId: 115 },
  { meta_key: 'title', meta_value: 'Mi titulo', postId: 115 },
  
]
```

lo que quiero obtener es un array como este

```
[
      { id:1353, meta_key: 'file', meta_value: 'undefined', postId: 115 },
      { id:1354, meta_key: 'title', meta_value: 'Mi titulo', postId: 115 }
      
    ]
```

al final quiero actualizar la meta pero no se como concatenar lo dos array

Comment: No parece que hayas hecho nada para solucionarlo. ¿que has probado y que errores te ha dado?  Repasa [ask] para mejorar la pregunta, sino puede ser considerada como "tarea que nos pasas a nosotros" y puede que sea cerrada por ese motivo, por falta de más detalles de lo que intentaste.

Comment: Concatenar es poner los elementos de un array al final del otro. No has explicado que contienennlos arrays? Tienen la misma longitud? Tampoco has explicado como se supone que se relacionan ambos arrays. Y como dijo masterguru, no has mostrado ningún esfuerzo de tu parte en intentar resolver el problema.

Comment: Interesante pregunta, pero de muy baja calidad, muéstranos lo que haz intentado, explícanos a más detalle y los errores que te surgieron, así con gusto podremos ayudarte =)

Comment: me disculpo por no ave detallado bien mi pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para concatenar dos arrays por posición tienes que usar `map` en el array que quieres transformar y obtener por cada iteración el valor y el indice y devolver el mismo objecto pero con la propiedad del otro array en la posicion del indice obtenido.

Prueba el siguiente código:

```js
const b = [{ id: 1353 }, { id: 1354 }]

const a = [
  { meta_key: 'file', meta_value: 'undefined', postId: 115 },
  { meta_key: 'title', meta_value: 'Mi titulo', postId: 115 },
  { meta_key: 'category', meta_value: '2', postId: 115 },
  { meta_key: 'purpose', meta_value: 'Venta', postId: 115 },
  { meta_key: 'price', meta_value: '$10,000 - $30,000 USD', postId: 115 },
]

const result = a.map((v, i) => ({ ...b[i], ...v }))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Franco Torres tu codigo a resulto mi problema mil gracias

Comment: Es un placer haberte ayudado. ¡Suerte!